# MongoDB with ASP.NET MVC: Creating MongoClient object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I am trying to set up an ASP.NET MVC5 project in Visual Studio 2013, using MongoDB. Here's what I have done so far:

1) Created the project in Visual Studio

2) Downloaded MongoDB.Bson.dll and MongoDB.Driver.dll

3) Added a reference to each of these two dll's in my Visual Studio project

4) Written the following code in HomeController.cs:

```
namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private MongoClient _client;
        private MongoServer _server;
        private MongoDatabase _database;

        public HomeController()
        {
            _client = new MongoClient(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Mongo"].ConnectionString);
            _server = _client.GetServer();
            _database = _server.GetDatabase(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DbName"]);
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run the Visual Studio debugger, I get the following message on the line that says `_client = new MongoClient(.....)`:

```
NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in MyProject.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Have I missed out something important? Thanks.

Comment: From a first look your code seems ok for me. You should check your connection string. It should look like this *mongodb://user1:password1@localhost/test*. For more information have a look at the [official documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/authenticate-with-csharp-driver/)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have a connection string called Mongo in your config file.

Double check you have the following:

```
<add name="Mongo" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/yourDatabase" />
```